# Display pho echo list in Descending order

Tags: php, sql-order-by, echo

Am displaying list haviing

```
Date

News Heading

Short Descrption
```

The list is spread to around 100 pages, having 20 news in each page

Issue is: This is working absolute fine in php 7.3, 7.4 in joomla 3.10 where on clicking url - list is shown spread over multiple pages having sort by date wise as first criteria, latest date of publishing is coming

But when same used on php 8.0.x - its showing incorrectly, where on clicking URL - last page of list having page number 100 is shown first. Now when i add on limitstart=0 in url then its showing correctly as the first page.

Now when i change from descending to ascending - its bringing the content on last page and its opening, but page number is 100 again

Seems like URL when opened is directly taking to last page of news item as published (although no limitstart is mentioned in it), which is incorrect as ideally should open in descending order and open the page having latest one

Below is code of views/list/tmpl/default.php

```
if(count($this->items) >0){
    //$i=1;
    
    foreach($this->items as $newslist)
    {
        $date = JFactory::getDate($newslist->n_date);
        $list .='<h3><strong>'.$newslist->v_heading.'</strong></h3>
        <p>'. $date->format('F j, Y').'</p>
        <p>'.substr($newslist->v_short_description,0,100).'</p>
        <p><i>Know More on:- </i><a href="index.php?option=com_news&view=detail&v_id='.$newslist->id.'&Itemid='.$Itemid.'"><b><i>'.$newslist->v_heading.'</i></b></a></p><hr/><br>';
                
        //$i=$i+1;
    }
}else{
        JError::raiseError(404, "Message");
    
}

<?php echo $list?>
```

and for models/list.php this is the function

```
protected function getListQuery()
    {
        // Create a new query object.
        $db    = $this->getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        // Select the required fields from the table.
        $query
            ->select(
                $this->getState(
                    'list.select', 'DISTINCT a.*'
                )
            );

        $query->from('`#__news` AS a');
                
        if (!JFactory::getUser()->authorise('core.edit', 'com_news'))
        {
            $query->where('a.state = 1');
        }

        // Filter by search in title
        $search = $this->getState('filter.search');

        if (!empty($search))
        {
            if (stripos($search, 'id:') === 0)
            {
                $query->where('a.id = ' . (int) substr($search, 3));
            }
            else
            {
                $search = $db->Quote('%' . $db->escape($search, true) . '%');
                $query->where('( a.n_heading LIKE ' . $search . ' )');
            }
        }
        
/*
        // Add the list ordering clause.
        $orderCol  = $this->state->get('list.ordering');
        $orderDirn = $this->state->get('list.direction');

        if ($orderCol && $orderDirn)
        {
            $query->order($db->escape($orderCol . ' ' . $orderDirn));
        }
*/      //Order by date
        
        $query->order ('a.n_date DESC');
        $query->order ('a.id DESC');
        
        return $query;
    }
```

This is the code for views/list/view.html.php

```
public function display($tpl = null)
    {
        $app = JFactory::getApplication();
        $this->state      = $this->get('State');
        $this->items = $this->get('Items');
        $this->pagination = $this->get('Pagination');
        $this->params     = $app->getParams('com_news');
        $this->filterForm = $this->get('FilterForm');
        $this->activeFilters = $this->get('ActiveFilters');
        // Check for errors.
        if (count($errors = $this->get('Errors')))
        {
            throw new Exception(implode("\n", $errors));
        }
        $this->_prepareDocument();
        parent::display($tpl);
    }
```

Unsure how to achieve in and why its not working in php 8.0 where url should open the 1st page and not last page

Comment: `ORDER BY` has to be in the SQL query, not PHP.

Comment: oH so it means its incorrect to do in above code, i should rather looks has Mysql function for it.

Comment: Yes, just like you said in your tag: `sql-order-by`.

Comment: You could also use the PHP `usort()` function to sort `$this->items`

Comment: Tried long, but unfortunately my bad been novice could not make it on to achieve in how to get it working. Starting bounty - if can help in workable.

Comment: To get the first page you, probably, should try using ASC instead of DESC at $query->order ('a.id DESC'); or $query->order ('a.n_date DESC'); (not sure what do you mean by 'last page' exactly)